# Need guidance w/ yml file

Tags: java, database, eclipse, configuration, yaml

Im trying to remove my database code from being hardcoded in my database connection class... so im trying to use a Application.yml file to pull the value to connect to the database ... below is the format of my application.yml class.
I created a regular DBConnection class but it isnt pulling from my application.yml file. I am using @Configuration, @ConfigurationProperties, nothing is working, I am getting a "ExceptionInInitializerError" and need help or guidance fixing it

```
datasource:
  url: XXXXXXX
  driverName:xxxxxxx
  username:xxxxxx
  password:xxxxx
```

Comment: if this is a spring project (is it)? Have you been through the docs, or walk through here? https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-yaml

Comment: It is a spring project, and not sure.. going to take a look at that link now! Thank you for the resources @juju